# How to extract the language of a pdf document

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to extract the language of any general pdf document and set it in CMS using python. I am trying to extract it using /Lang attribute, here is the code sample:

```
pdfFileLang = findInDict('/Lang',pdfFile.resolvedObjects())



def findInDict(needle,indirectObjectDict):
    """ Returns the PDF Language """
    haystack = indirectObjectDict[0]
    LOG('pypdfutils.py getPdfLanguage key haystack',INFO,str(haystack))
    for key in haystack.keys():
        LOG('pypdfutils.py getPdfLanguage key',INFO,str(key))
        try:
             value = haystack[key]
             LOG('pypdfutils.py getPdfLanguage value',INFO,str(value))
             if key == needle:
                 return value
             else:
                 LOG('pypdfutils.py getPdfLanguage value1',INFO,str(value))
             internalDict = value.keys()
             LOG('pypdfutils.py getPdfLanguage key Dict',INFO,str(internalDict))
             if type(value) == types.DictType:
                 internalDict = value.keys()                 
             else:
                 LOG('pypdfutils.py getPdfLanguage value2',INFO,str(value))
                 for internalkey in internalDict.keys():
                     internalvalue = internalDict[internalkey]
                     LOG('pypdfutils.py getPdfLanguage key internalvalue',INFO,str(internalvalue))
                     if type(internalvalue) == types.DictType and internalvalue.has_key(needle):
                         return internalvalue[needle]                                  
        except Exception,e:
            LOG('pypdfutils.py getPdfLanguage',INFO,str(e))
            continue
```

But when I am seeing the LOGS I find no such attribute "/Lang" in the dictionary.

Comment: What library are you using to read the pdf? Please link to it. Are you sure there is a /Lang attribute in the file?

Comment: I am using pypdf to read it. I am using /Lang attribute to get the language which comes under Advanced tab of PDFs document properties.

Comment: http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/jsunpack-n/source/browse/trunk/pdf.py?r=27

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you tried to search for 'Lang' key through all dictionaries in your PDF file.

To check the language information from a PDF file, you need to check 'Lang' entry in the catalog.
However the existance of this entry depends on PDF creating software which is used to create the PDF file and most PDF files do not have this entry.

I do not understand Python code but I belive that the PDF library you are using will provide you the access to the trailer (dictionary) or catalog (root) dictionray. If you have an access to the trailer dict, get 'Root' value from the dict. This is the indirect reference to Catalog (Root) dictionary. Then resolve this reference to dict to get the catalog dictionary. Taking /Lang value from this catalog dict will give you the attribute.

Try, the following

```
catalog = pdfFile.trailer['/Root'].getObject()
if has_key("/Lang"):
    lang = catalog['/Lang'].getObject()
```

Please note that I am not a Python programmer and the code snippet above is my first Python code (I am not sure it is working. :-)

Please refer pypdf reference at http://sourcecodebrowser.com/python-pypdf/1.10/classpy_pdf_1_1pdf_1_1_pdf_file_reader.html#a92be75503c895367083a846b3060e632

Comment: yes, Oleg you are getting it right, I want to search through all dictionaries in PDF file. I think we can access the language of a PDF document(e.g. English, french etc) using "/Lang" attribute. i am not concerned about one page rather i want to get the language which is set for a particular PDF file in Document properties under "Advanced" tab.

Comment: Ranjan, then you need to check the existance of /Lang key in your PDF file. And you don't need to go through all dicts. /Lang key will be in your Catalog dictionary which is refered as Root in the trailer.

Comment: Can you give me an example for what you have explained in last sentence i.e. about Catalog dictionary refered as Root as i am not clear about this thing. it would be really helpful.

Comment: Actually I don't understand Python code. However I belive that your PDF library will provide you the access to the trailer (dictionary) or root dictionray directly. If you have access to the trailer dict, get 'Root' value from the dict. This is the Catalog (Root) dictionary. Get /Lang value from this catalog!

Comment: I guess 'pdfFile.catalog.get('Lang')' will return the value you want.

Comment: Oleg, I tried this one but its not working. I put a LOG but the code stops at this line and then prints nothing after that not even a single line.Firstly i tried to print catalog to see what are the contents but nothing got printed.In short, this line is not even read neither the lines ahead of it. Please look into it once again.

Comment: @Ranjan, I think it stops there because that no /Lang entry found in your PDF file. Just check the existance of /Lang key in pdfFile.catalog first. If not, your PDF does not have language attribute.

Comment: We are setting the language attributes ourselves then we are uploading it, so this cant be the case that the PDF has no language attribute because we are setting it before uploading it to CMS. Problems arise when we are trying to fetch the same through the code. It also stops when we are only writing "pdfFile.catalog" and then try to print the catalog in LOGS to see the content of catalog.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the PDF specification:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html

There is a "/Lang" key in the Document Catalog. In my version of the PDF specification this is explained in section 7.7.2.

This language key defines the language assumed for the complete document, with the exception of those parts that are marked differently.

So, two caveats:
1) This "/Lang" key is optional. If it's not there the PDF specification says the language is undefined.

2) This "/Lang" key may be overwritten by other elements in the file. So the entire document may be English, but specific sentences on page 101 may redefine the language as French for example.

In your case, your algorithm should first try to find the overall document language as defined above. If that's not there it's up to you what to do. You could search the complete document for "/Lang" keys to see if you find any other, but if you find multiple, you'll have to decide what that means...

Comment: Can you give us some examples that how to get the overall document language.It would be quite helpful.

Comment: No, I don't write python unfortunately.